# Module 'KissXML' not found in Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

As I am trying to integrate with xmppframework using the

> pod 'XMPPFramework'

but its not helpful to solve the issue get the same issue Module "KissXML" not found

> pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

with some other stack overflow suggestions but this also showing the same error of "kissXML" not found.

But previously I tried to with Xcode 10.3 its working perfectly.

Please give any suggestions to install the xmppframework through pod with running successfully.

Comment: try with  `pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 4.0'`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I already having this only


- XMPPFramework (4.0.0):
    - XMPPFramework/default (= 4.0.0)
  - XMPPFramework/default (4.0.0):
    - CocoaAsyncSocket (~> 7.6)
    - CocoaLumberjack
    - KissXML (~> 5.2)
    - libidn (~> 1.35)

Answer (score 0):

I got it after the long time of finding this issue, just use the

> use_frameworks!

before giving the pod names especially xmppframework.

from the reference of : https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/790
but still this was an open only not yet closed.